# How to do Node js redirection as HTTP POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have configure *app.js*  to redirect all request to my *controller.js*.
The following is an example of how my *controller.js* looks like.

```
router.all('/Controller/:id', controller);
function controller(req, res){
    //db check using the id mentioned in the url. And gets some values.
    //Say it is stored in data variable.
    var URL = "SOMEURL";
    if(data != null){
        if(data.METHOD == "POST"){
            // needs to redirect as HTTP POST with URL.
        }else{
            res.redirect(URL);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('No Data Found to redirect');
    }
}
```

You can see that i need to redirect to a specific *URL* if the *data.METHOD* is *POST*. I tried *res.redirect*, but all it gives is a *GET request*. So How can i redirect as **HTTP POST** to a specific url? Please provide me a your ideas.

thanks and regards.

Comment: from the top of my head, I would say that you need to create a new post request on that method, and return the response to the caller, maybe there are other ways.. or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Why redirect?  You have the data, you already know what you need to do.  Why not just break the code you want to execute into a function on your server where it can be used by both your other route and called right here?  It seems like you're doing a pointless redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you set up individual methods for each condition.

One for a GET, one for a POST,PUT etc. This way you can have testable code and not break the Single Responsibility Principle

```
router.get('/Controller/:id', controller.GetData);
router.put('/Controller/', controller.UpdateData);
router.post('/Controller/', controller.SaveData);
```

for put and post you can pass the data in the request.body

Comment: Yeah i got it. But all i wanted to do is to rediect as post to a url from the controller. so how can i do it?

Comment: you can use the request module.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys..

found my answer.

all i need to do is redirect with 307 HTTP status. The following will redirect to the post Router.

```
res.redirect(307, URL);
```